# Is this relation in BCNF?

Tags: relational-database

I have a relation

```
Competitor(PID, EventName, Pname, TeamName, TeamCoach,EventDate, TeamRating).
```

and I have my FDs

```
PID -> Pname
PID --> TeamName
TeamName --> TeamCoach
EventName --> EventDate
TeamName, EventName --> TeamRating
```

which will form into my relations

```
Competitor(_PID_, Pname, TeamName*)
Team(_TeamName_, TeamCoach)
Event(_EventName_, EventDate)
Rating(_TeamName_*, _EventName_*, TeamRating)
Entry(_PID_*, _EventName_*)
```

However, since my candidate key is {PID, EventName}, how can the Team relation be in BCNF if TeamName is not even part of the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of FDs as written down in your question, applies to a single relation schema.  The set of FDs as they apply to a given relation schema, determines what the keys will be **to that relation schema**.

For example, your set of 5 FDs corresponds to the 7-column relation schema that you started with.  And that set of FDs allows to determine that the key to your 7-column relation schema is indeed {PID EventName}.

But if you split that 7-column schema in parts, then this has its consequences for which FDs are still applicable, and to which of the parts.

For example.  Suppose you single out

```
 Team(_TeamName_, TeamCoach)
```

and leave

```
 Competitor(PID, EventName, Pname, TeamName, EventDate, TeamRating).
```

For each of the individual FDs, you now have to decide to which of the two new relation schemas that individual FD applies.

In the example at hand :

```
 Team(_TeamName_, TeamCoach)
 TeamName --> TeamCoach

 Competitor(PID, EventName, Pname, TeamName, EventDate, TeamRating)
 PID -> Pname
 PID --> TeamName
 EventName --> EventDate
 TeamName, EventName --> TeamRating
```

You now have not only two relation schemas, **but also two distinct sets of FDs that apply to them, respectively**.  The teamname->teamcoach FD now no longer applies to the (revised) Competitor relation schema, but only to the Team schema.  This allows you to conclude that TeamName will be a key **to the Team schema**.

BTW it will not always be possible to retain **all** the FDs that you started out with.  An FD whose overall set of attributes (left-hand side plus right-hand side) is such that after the schema split, there no longer is any relation schema that includes all those attributes, such an FD can simply no longer be expressed, and must be reinstated in the resulting design as a database constraint that does not take on the form of an FD (/key).  That is the issue of "dependency preservation".

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Also got it clarified with my uni tutor. He said the same thing.